# Combine rows in a table using the a column as reference [PSQL]

Tags: psql

I have a postgresql table like this:

```
| id   | date       | status |
|------|------------|--------|
| id1  | 2019-01-01 | ON     |
| id1  | 2019-01-02 | OFF    |
| id1  | 2019-01-03 | ON     |
```

How can I combine the rows into sth like this:

```
| id   | on_date    | off_date   |
|------|------------|------------|
| id1  | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-02 |
| id1  | 2019-01-03 |            |
```

`OFF` status always inserted after `ON` status (there will be a on_date before off_date)

My current solution is:

```
WITH ons AS (
  SELECT id, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY date) as row_num, date as on_date
  FROM table
  WHERE status = 'ON' AND id = id1),
offs AS (
  SELECT id, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY date) as row_num, date as off_date
  FROM table
  WHERE status = 'OFF' AND id = id1)
SELECT ons.id, ons.on_date, offs.off_date 
FROM ons
LEFT JOIN offs ON ons.id = off.id AND ons.row_num = offs.row_num
```

Can I do this with simpler query? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use below SQL :

```
select tt.id, tt.date as on_date, (select idate from 
table where id=tt.id and status='OFF' and 
date>=tt.idate and rownum<2) as off_date from table tt
where status='ON'
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think you get the result using below query:**

`SELECT id,on_date,off_date from (SELECT id,date as on_date,'' as off_date FROM test WHERE status = 'ON' UNION ALL SELECT id,'' as on_date,date as off_date FROM test WHERE status = 'OFF') as a`